# Spring MVC + Hibernate : Unknown entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, sprite

I'm really new in Java world and scpecificly in Spring. I try to read a lot of tutoriel but I'm really confused.
I create some entity mapped by annotation, I succed to persist it when I load my Application Context in a main class but I can't do it in my controller.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private Long idUser;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable=false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable=false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable=false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable=false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "birth")
    private Date birth;

    @Column(name = "avatar")
    private String avatar;

...



}
```

I have make sur to use javax.persistence.

In my dispachtcher servlet I load my spring-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.manager.spring" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <import resource="classpath*:spring-config.xml" />

</beans>
```

Spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- This sescion tells Spring context where to look for bean classes with appropriate annotations -->
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.manager.spring"></context:component-scan>


      <!-- Configure JDBC Connection-->
      <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/calendar" />
            <property name="username" value="root" />
            <property name="password" value="pass" />
      </bean>

      <!-- Configure Hibernate 4 Session Facotry -->
      <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
          <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
          </property>
          <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                      <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                </props>
          </property>
          <property name="annotatedClasses">
                <list>
                      <value>com.manager.spring.entity.Event</value>
                      <value>com.manager.spring.entity.User</value>
                      <value>com.manager.spring.entity.DroitEvent</value>


       </list>
      </property>
</bean>
```

I create a Service for User

```
@Service("userSvc")
public class UserService {

       @Autowired
       private UserDAO userDAO;

       public void setUserDAO(UserDAO userDAO) {
             this.userDAO = userDAO;
       }

       public void create(User user){
           userDAO.create(user);
       }
}
```

And my UserDAO

```
@Component("userDAO")//This the id by which it will be auto wired
public class UserDAO extends BaseDAO{

       public void create(User user){
           try{
                getSession().save(user);
            }
            catch(HibernateException e){
                System.out.println("Error occured while saving data"+e.getMessage());
            }
       }


}
```

BaseDAO :

```
public class BaseDAO {

    @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
           this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    protected Session getSession(){
           return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }     
}
```

And this config is working when I create a user in a main class

```
 ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring-config.xml"});

  UserService userSvc = (UserService) ctx.getBean("userSvc");
  userSvc.create(user);
```

But when I try to create a user in my controller, I get an exception

```
Error occured while saving dataUnknown entity: com.manager.spring.entity.User
```

I really hope someone can help me, I'm not sur to have understand everything and I'm very sorry for my poor english !
Thx

Comment: You show the `Event` entity but it complains about your `User` entity.

Comment: Oh damn ! Sorry, I have edit it.

Comment: Is `spring-config.xml` meant to be `Spring-context.xml`, or vice versa? I'd also like to see `BaseDAO`.

Comment: I don't really know... I sid I was very confused with Spring...
I add BaseDao on the question.